# Mule 3.3.0 - global property not being resolved from properties file

Tags: mule

The global property is not being resolved from properties file, as a result of which mmc deployment fails. Any ides why what could be wrong?

```
<context:property-placeholder location="airports.properties" />
<global-property name="airportslist" value="${airportslist}" />
```

Getting the following exception --

```
com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.v3.dto.DeploymentException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [file:/arprt/mule-esb-ee/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0/apps/myapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/myapp-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'airportslist' (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
        at com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.service.impl.ApplicationServiceImpl.deploy(ApplicationServiceImpl.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

airports.properties contains the above mentioned property:

```
  airportslist={'SFO', 'YYZ', 'DFW'}
```

Comment: +1 good question, am facing same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to declare a `global-property` if the property is defined in a properties file and loaded with the `context:property-placeholder`.

Just remove:

```
<global-property name="airportslist" value="${airportslist}" />
```

and use `${airportslist}` anywhere you need it in your config.

Comment: You are right. But I am just curious shouldn't the property still be resolved?

Comment: Mmmh, you're hitting a potential ordering problem: the global-var is probably resolved before the property placeholder gets loaded. Global vars are supposed to be used alongside props, not in conjunction with.

Comment: @DavidDossot, I've a similar use-case where `airportslist` `<global-property>` value is coming from property placeholder but don't think that cane be replaced by just `${airportslist}` because in flow, it is being used as `<when expression="#[app.registry.airportslist.contains(message.payload)]">`. Here `airportslist` is defined as `ArrayList` to use the method `contains()` to check if `payload` has the airport defined in `${airportslist}`. Airportslist is not hardcoded as this list varies  within environments. Please suggest what can be a better alternative in this case.

Comment: Please don't ask a new question in a comment.