# Mule Global property not being resolved from properties file

Tags: exception, properties, mule, global

I try to use global property in mule flow:

```
    <global-property name="SS_Out" value="${streamserve.dir.outbound}" doc:name="Global Property"/>
    <global-property name="SI_In" value="${sendinvoice.dir.inbound}" doc:name="Global Property"/>
    <global-property name="E2B_In" value="${streamserve.dir.e2boperational}" doc:name="Global Property"/>
```

to get and use these properties in Java code:

```
       public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

         MuleMessage message = eventContext.getMessage();
         MuleContext muleContext = eventContext.getMuleContext();

         Object originalSSOutputFilePathProperty = muleContext.getRegistry().get("SS_Out");
         Object originalSSInputFilePathProperty = muleContext.getRegistry().get("SI_In");
         Object originalE2BInputFilePathProperty = muleContext.getRegistry().get("E2B_In");
```

but I have got the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'streamserve.dir.outbound' in string   
value "${streamserve.dir.outbound}"
```

Please advice, thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you defining the properties? In a properties file?

Comment: Yes,in a properties file

Answer (score 0):

Mule global properties need not be defined in a properties file. All the properties loaded by property-holder into mule are global properties and can be access directly .

```
${property.name}
```

Refer to the following stackoverflow answer.

[Mule 3.3.0 - global property not being resolved from properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782396/mule-3-3-0-global-property-not-being-resolved-from-properties-file)

Comment: I know about it.But I need to set value for global property from property file - relative path to file. For example, value="${streamserve.dir.outbound}" for record in property files.

Comment: At the code block where you want o use the GlobalProperty  you can directly use the ${streamserve.dir.outbound}. This is the solution. Resolving global-property from properties file will not work in Mule.

Comment: Please, give short example how I can directly use the ${streamserve.dir.outbound} in Java code. Really, I don't understand.

Comment: Are you looking to use the Global Property in Java class rather than in the Flow config? Add the code where you are using this Global Property.